# How to check: is the User logged in with angular-6-social-login npm package?

Tags: angular, angular-guards, angular-social-login

I have successfully integrated with angular-6-social-login (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-social-login) to login into my angular APP using google account.

I am creating an Angular Guard to protect the routes so that only users can access after logging in. The AuthService from angular-6-social-login does not support any direct function to see if the user has logged in or not. Any suggestions here, please?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from 'angular-6-social-login';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginGuardGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(nextRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    const requiresLogin = nextRoute.data.requiresLogin || false;
    console.log("AccessGuard canActivate is being called")

      // Check that the user is logged in...
      //TODO: need help with the if condition
      if (!<userLoggedin>) { 
      this.router.navigate(['login'])  
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have successfully logged in, Facebook/Google will provide unique access token for a particular user.

For example in Google:
`userData.getAuthResponse().id_token;`

This token can be stored in Cookies/localStorage/sessionStorage according to your application needs and check if this token is available at the auth guard.

Example:

```
localStorage.setItem("APP_TOKEN", userData.getAuthResponse().id_token);
```

AuthGuard:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  if (!localStorage.getItem("APP_TOKEN")) {
    this.router.navigate(['login'])  
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

This token can also be used with your backend server to validate the current user. More details on this link [ID Token Auth](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth). For Facebook [FB Access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)

Make sure to clear this token and call an api to invalidate this token on Logout.

```
localStorage.removeItem("APP_TOKEN")
```

Comment: just wondering, if localstorage be manipulated? should I check against the backend server within CanActivate?

Comment: You can do that as well, but I would prefer other way. Suppose after login, if you are navigating to PageA and if the localStorage token is manipulated, any api calls in PageA will return you a 401 unauthorized as there will be a backend validation (Note: we will be passing the token in the header for all the api calls). Based on 401 response, clear the localStorage and redirect back to login page.

Comment: just with the token in the client end alas some key.. how it is possible to justify the user is authenticated, I don't think the OP question is about persistence, in javascript website, there is a redirect URL, not be able to use such option in angular/SPA